# WPF (.NET 6) does not correctly load references using Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: .net, wpf, dll

In the sample solution there are 3 projects

1. *MainApp* - main WPF app
2. *MyPlugin* - dynamically loaded plugin
3. *Components* - WPF components (this could be nuget package)

When starting *MainApp*, the *MyPlugin.dll* is loaded using *Assembly.LoadFrom*, scanned for all *IPlugin* implementations and all implementations are loaded.

The problem is that *MyPlugin* internally references *Components* (which is **not** referenced in *MainApp*) and when loading an *UserControl* from it, we get this exception

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Components, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

even though *Components.dll* is located in root folder.

It can be fixed by

1. Referencing *Components* from *MainApp* directly **but that defeats the purpose of plugins**
2. Calling *Assembly.LoadFrom("Components.dll")* before using it **but that adds complexity**

It is working just fine in our current *.NET Framework* implementation.

Is *Assembly.LoadFrom* not enough in .NET 6 anymore? Is there an alternative?

Source code to reproduce https://github.com/rholek/DependencyIssue

Comment: It is there (all projects build into this path). Also Assembly.LoadFrom("Components.dll") works, so the file must be there

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1700